# Firefox Build Error: old-configure failed

Tags: firefox, build, mozilla, llvm-clang

I'm trying to build Firefox(60.esr) from source. I followed the steps mentioned in [Build Firefox on Windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites). But it fails.

**Method #1:**
I followed all the steps mentioned in the Windows Build Instruction. 
The Build process failed with error.

```
 0:24.36 ERROR: Could not find LLVM/Clang installation for compiling stylo build-time
 0:24.36 bindgen.  Please specify the 'LLVM_CONFIG' environment variable
 0:24.36 (recommended), pass the '--with-libclang-path' and '--with-clang-path'
 0:24.36 options to configure, or put 'llvm-config' in your PATH.  Altering your
 0:24.36 PATH may expose 'clang' as well, potentially altering your compiler,
 0:24.36 which may not be what you intended.
```

So, I tried method 2.

**Method #2:**
Since it was expecting LLVM/clang, I installed LLVM/Clang 6.0 and added ‘*LLVM_CONFIG*’ to the environment variable.

And then I executed `mach build`. Adding LLVM_CONFIG fixed the error which was caused in Method 1.
But the build failed again with error.

```
 0:16.24 c:/Users/n182s826/mozilla/mozilla-central/old-configure: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
 0:18.59 m.AllocationBase 0x0, m.BaseAddress 0x607A0000, m.RegionSize 0x240000, m.State 0x10000
 0:18.59 C:\mozilla-build\msys\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap (0x607A0000 <0xB80000>) in child, Win32 error 0
 0:18.59       0 [main] sh 13328 sync_with_child: child 14220(0x3B8) died before initialization with status code 0x1
 0:18.59      51 [main] sh 13328 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
 0:18.59 c:/Users/n182s826/mozilla/mozilla-central/old-configure: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
 0:18.61 ERROR: old-configure failed
 0:18.65 *** Fix above errors and then restart with\
 0:18.65                "c:/mozilla-build/mozmake/mozmake.EXE -f client.mk build"
```

I even raised a request at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1470008). But I haven't found any solution.

Comment: Are you running the commands from a MozillaBuild shell?

Comment: @Dexter Yeah. I'm running these commands through the MozillaBuild shell.

Comment: Did `./mach boostrap` fail with some error?